# Is there a way to open a new GUI if the Create Account or Login Button is pressed?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I'm making a banking system and I have the welcome page done and it works great. However, I do not know where to go from here. When you click on either of the buttons that pop up, I want that window to close and I want to have another open through a separate class which will proceed to do what is needed. For example, if I were to click the Create New Account button, I'd want the welcome page to close, and a new GUI page to open which would contain whatever is needed to create a new account. I don't know how to detect if the button was pressed, thus calling the new class. I also don't know how to how to automatically close a window when something happens.

Here is my code thus far:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Welcome implements ActionListener
{
    private static JLabel welcome1;
    private static JLabel welcome2;
    private static JButton createButton;
    private static JButton loginButton;

public Welcome()
{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(1920,1080);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(panel);
    
    panel.setLayout(null);
    
    welcome1 = new JLabel("Welcome to the");
    welcome1.setBounds(545,0,500,80);
    welcome1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 60));
    panel.add(welcome1);
    
    welcome2 = new JLabel("Valeduxian National Bank!");
    welcome2.setBounds(395,75,715,80);
    welcome2.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 60));
    panel.add(welcome2);
    
    createButton = new JButton("Create New Account");
    createButton.setBounds(225,450,500,80);
    createButton.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 48));
    //createButton.addActionListener(new Welcome()); COMMENTED OUT BC ITS NOT BEING USED 
    panel.add(createButton);
    
    loginButton = new JButton("Login to Exisiting Account");
    loginButton.setBounds(815,450,500,80);
    loginButton.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 32));
    //loginButton.addActionListener(new Welcome()); COMMENTED OUT BC ITS NOT BEING USED
    panel.add(loginButton);
    
    frame.setVisible(true);
    
    
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
     
}
```

}

Here is my main class:

```
import homePage.Welcome;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Welcome();

    }

}
```

Comment: You wrote in your question: _I don't know how to detect if the button was pressed_ You add an [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) to that `JButton`.

Comment: _I also don't know how to how to automatically close a window_ Call method [dispose](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#dispose()).

Comment: `panel.setLayout(null);` It is recommended to use a [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) I think [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) is appropriate for displaying the different GUI pages.

Comment: Don't relay on `static`, in this context, `static` is not your friend

Answer (score -1):

In order to programmatically close the window you need to call:

```
frame.dispose();
```

or just

```
dispose();
```

In order to open up a new window while doing so you will need to create some code similar to the implementation of you welcome class and then you action preformed should look something like this (Consider that OtherWindow will be your new class):

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    dispose();
    new OtherWindow();
 
}
```